# React Native Bootsplash Library - Android resource linking failed

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

I installed the Bootsplash library and it works fine on iOS. But when I want to run it on Android, I get the following error;
ERROR:quiz_app/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/debug/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:5506: AAPT: error: resource color/bootsplash_background (aka com.quiz_app:color/bootsplash_background) not found.

My assets folder includes **SplashScreenLogo.png**

`MainActivity.java`

[image]
[image: MainActivity.java]
[image: styles.xml]

react-native version: 0.72.6
react-native-bootsplash version: 5.0.4

How can I fix this problem ?

Thanks for reading.

I changed the name of my SplashScreenLogo.png file to bootsplash_logo but it didn't work.
I ran the ./gradlew clean command and compiled the application again but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely happening because you haven't created (or modified) the **colors.xml** file properly. The color `bootsplash_background` is missing from the file.

Navigate to `android/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml` in your project (or create the file if it doesn't exist) and add the following content:

```
<resources>
    <color name="bootsplash_background">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

If the file already has some colors defined, just add the  `bootsplash_background` one under any color and rebuild the app.